# Limit Challenge

Tags: calculus

I have tried very hard to manipulate this limit, but can't seem to find what the answer is. Can someone give me an explanation to what the limit would be.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{-n}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {n^i}{i!} $$

Comment: Would it be 1/2?

Comment: Correct. 
${}{}{}$

Comment: How about this one?

Comment: Changing completely the content of a question is a bad behavior here on SE. Please refrain from such act, if you have another question make a new thread.

Comment: Ok sorry about that. I thought because this question already existed, I would change the question here to avoid confusion.